# Deploy is not killing the old Puma process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mina-deploy

I'm having trouble finding out why, when performing a new deployment, a new instance of Puma is being initialized and not shutting down the old ones, which ends up consuming a lot of machine resources.

I've already reviewed the deployment script and can't find any problem or reason for this to happen.

For the deployment, I'm using the mina gem, and to run the entire deployment process, I have two files.
One of them is the bin/deploy file where I have shell commands to sequentially run the mina commands, and the other is the default mina deployment file.

```bash
# bin/deploy file
system "mina deploy"
system "mina puma:stop"
system "mina puma_clean"
system "mina puma:start"
```

```rb
# mina deploy.rb
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/rvm'
require 'mina/puma'
require 'mina/whenever'
require 'mina/git'

# -- Basic settings:
set :application_name, 'app'
set :user, 'app'
set :domain, '8.8.8.8'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/app'
set :repository, 'git@github.com:repository.git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :rails_env, 'production'

# -- RVM
set :rvm_use_path, "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
task :remote_environment do
  invoke :'rvm:use', 'ruby-3.1.2'
end

# -- Shared Dirs
set :shared_dirs, fetch(:shared_dirs, []).push(
  'pids','log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle',
  'public/system', 'public/assets', 'public/packs', 'node_modules'
)
set :shared_files, fetch(:shared_files, []).push('config/database.yml')

# -- Setup
task :setup do
  command %{rvm install ruby-3.1.2}
  command %{gem install bundler}
end

# -- If puma thinks it's running but ain't
task :puma_clean do
  command "rm /var/www/app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma*"
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy do
  invoke :'git:ensure_pushed'
  deploy do
    command %(source ~/.profile)
    command %(source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh)
    command %(nvm use 18.12.1)
    command %(node -v)
    command %(ruby -v)

    invoke :'git:clone'
    #invoke :'sidekiq:stop'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    on :launch do
      in_path(fetch(:current_path)) do
        command %(source ~/.profile)
        
        invoke :'puma:restart'

        invoke :'whenever:update'
        
        command %{mkdir -p tmp/}
        command %{touch tmp/restart.txt}
      end
    end
  end

  run(:local){ puts 'Done!' }
end
```

And as specified, even with this code, I'm having issues with multiple instances of Puma on the machine as shown in the image below

[image]

I've already conducted several searches for a command that terminates the Puma PIDs during deployment but haven't succeeded, and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

**EDIT:**
So, I checked the terminal again during the deployment, and I noticed that when it executes the mina puma:stop command, it triggers the following output:

```
-----> Using RVM environment "ruby-3.1.2"
       Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2
-----> Stopping Puma...
       Puma is not running!
       Connection to 8.8.8.8 closed.

       Elapsed time: 2.14 seconds
```

I searched for this message Puma is not running! in the mina puma repository but couldn't find it. Do you believe this means that at the moment of stop, it's not able to terminate the old Puma process?

Comment: Shot in the dark here but maybe your bin/deploy is causing issues with your deploy.rb rake tasks?  It appears the rake tasks should take care of everything for you so what happens if you remove the bin/deploy file? Is it also possible that puma is running under a different account than the deployment? I have seen this with passenger/nginx installs in single user mode.

Comment: I did this just now, and indeed, what was creating the new instances of Puma was some of the commands present in bin/deploy, but I'm still having an issue when deploy.rb executes the puma:restart command. It still can't find the running Puma service/pid and gives me the message puma is not running!.

Comment: Have you confirmed that puma is running when you deploy? Do you only have 1 instance of puma after deployment? Another option could be to try `hard_restart` which runs stop and start rather than restart? Again just guessing at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I ran the htop command and there is only one instance of Puma running, so this problem was partially fixed. I'll test the command you mentioned, but I believe the issue isn't with the command itself, but somehow, the gem mina/puma isn't finding the running Puma instance, thus it's unable to manage it in any way (start, stop, restart), resulting in the message puma is not running!.

Comment: I would revise your entire question (or ask a new one) in regards to the specific issue you are now experiencing as the current question is focused on the multiple instances issue (which it appears we have solved)

Comment: You're right, I'll open a new question. Thank you!